# Center a map on button click only once and not again when other props/state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button that should center the map to the current geolocation, but only once, when the button is clicked.

After the position on the map was centered once (the map component handles that in `componentDidUpdate`)

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  onCenter() {
    this.setState({center: this.props.geolocation})
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return (nextProps.items !== this.props.items 
        || nextState.center != this.state.center) {
  }

  render() {
    <div>
      <Button onClick={this.center}/>
      <Map center={this.state.center} items={this.props.item}/>
    </div>
  }
}
```

Clicking the button will trigger a `render` and the map will be centered on the geolocation handed in as props.
However, when the `items` change, the map also centers again on `this.state.center`, which is not desired (the user might have moved the map around).

I thought of clearing the `state.center` in `componentDidUpdate` like this:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  if (this.state.center) {
    this.setState({center:null})
  }
}
```

and to stop a recursive render loop, extending `shouldComponentUpdate`

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  return (nextProps.items !== this.props.items 
          || (nextState.center != this.state.center && nextState.center)) {
  }
}
```

So the component, after being rendered, does not render again, even when `state.center` was changed right after the `render` call.

But that feels like a bad hack.

Any ideas?

Comment: why dont you check for state in your center function.. if (!this.state.iscentered) ....center it, otherwise not.. you might need to add something to state, like iscentered

Comment: why are you using a state variable to center the data? you should only center via data change in your didUpdate function. `componentDidUpdate(prevProps){ if(prevProps.somevalue !== this.props.someValue) {//call my center function to center the map}}`

Comment: @john the map is not an object, it's another component that takes the center as a prop. But u are right, the map could take off it, itself.